# Issue while loading image from a different directory

Tags: html, css, jsp

`[index.jsp][1]`
[style.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87S2A.jpg)

```
[issue][3]
[directory structure][4]
```

While The file is present in css directory all works fine but when it is kept in images folder it doesn't display any images. Please help

Answer (score 0):

I think it's issue related your URL line which you have added. If your CSS file & image in same CSS folder then please make sure your CSS as per below.
**background:url('OGSLogo.png') no-repeat;**

If you have added image file in images folder and CSS file in CSS folder then please make sure your CSS as per below.
**background:url('../images/OGSLogo.png') no-repeat;**